# Excel Delete rows between two specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, cell, rows

I want to delete all rows between two cells containing specific text.

For example: Cell `B16` contains `Description` and cell `B28` contains `Transportation`. I want to delete all rows between the rows of the cells containing `Description` and `Transportation`.
I need a VBA solution to solve this.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Punith

Comment: Hello Punith, StackOverflow doesn't provide ready-to-use codes. Instead, the user shall try on his own and then shall describe the difficulty in specific terms. What have you tried?

Comment: **UNCLEAR**  do want to delete rows *17* through *27* or rows *16* through *28* **??**

Answer (score 2):

## Delete Rows Between Criterias

- Change the values in the **constants** section to fit your needs.
- First test the code with `Hide` (`Const cDel As Boolean = False`).
  When you're sure it does what you desire, change `cDel` to `True` to
  delete Critical Rows (`Const cDel As Boolean = True`).
- The rows containing the **Criterias** (Description, Transportation) will
  **not** be deleted (hidden).
- If either **Criteria** is not found, the code will do nothing.

### The Code

```
Sub HideDeleteDT()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"        ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cStr1 As String = "Description"     ' Criteria 1
    Const cStr2 As String = "Transportation"  ' Criteria 2
    Const cCol As Variant = "B"               ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cDel As Boolean = False             ' Enable Delete(True), Hide(False)

    Dim Find1 As Range  ' Criteria 1 Cell Range
    Dim Find2 As Range  ' Criteria 2 Cell Range
    Dim LCell As Range  ' Last Cell in Criteria Column

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        ' In Criteria Column
        With .Columns(cCol)
            ' Assign last cell range in Criteria Column to variable.
            Set LCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
            ' Find Criteria 1 and assign the found cell range to variable.
            Set Find1 = .Find(cStr1, LCell, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns)
        End With
        ' Check if Criteria 1 was found.
        If Not Find1 Is Nothing Then
            ' Find Criteria 2 and assign the found cell range to variable.
            Set Find2 = .Range(Find1.Offset(1), LCell).Find(cStr2, LCell)
            ' Check if Criteria 2 was found.
            If Not Find2 Is Nothing Then
                ' To prevent hiding or deleting rows of the Criteria Cell Ranges
                ' after Critical Rows have already been deleted (Delete) or(and)
                ' the Criterias are in concecutive rows (Hide).
                If Find1.Row + 1 < Find2.Row Then
                    ' Hide or delete rows between found Criteria Cell Ranges.
                    If cDel Then ' Delete (Unsafe). You will lose data.
                        .Rows(Find1.Row + 1 & ":" & Find2.Row - 1).Delete
                      Else       ' Hide (Safe). No loss of data.
                        ' Show all rows to visualize what exactly is being
                        ' hidden by the code each time i.e. if rows have
                        ' previously been hidden it would be unclear which ones
                        ' have been hidden each ('this') time.
                        .Rows.Hidden = False
                        .Rows(Find1.Row + 1 & ":" & Find2.Row - 1).Hidden = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

### Find Method Remarks

- The 1st argument, **What**, contains the data to search for and is **required**. All other arguments are optional.
- The 2nd argument, **After**, is set to the Last Cell 'after which it
  starts searching' from the first (upper (left)) cell in the column (range) indicated by the omitted
  *default* **SearchDirection** parameter `xlNext`.
- The 3rd, 4th and 5th arguments, **LookIn**, **LookAt** and
  **SearchOrder**, are saved each time and can therefore be omitted in the second Search (`Set Find2 = ...`).

  - **LookIn** is set to `xlValues` to prevent
    searching in formulas (or comments).
  - **LookAt** is set to `xlWhole` to prevent finding
    parts of the **What** parameter in the cells e.g. `Type Description` will not be found.
  - **SearchOrder** could safely be omitted, since we're searching in a one-column range.
- The 6th argument, **SearchDirection**, is by *default* `xlNext` which
  is used in the code and can therefore be safely omitted.
- The 7th argument, **MatchCase**, is by *default* `False` which isn't
  addressed in the OP's question and is therefore omitted.

Comment: I've edited the **code** for the 2nd time, this time concerning the lines  **If Find1.Row + 1 < Find2.Row Then** and **.Rows.Hidden = False**. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a helper function that accepts the range to scan, the text to search and the found range as parameters and returns `True` if the found range is actually found:

```
Function GetCellWithText(rngToScan As Range, txtToSearch As String, foundRng As Range) As Boolean
    With rngToScan
        Set foundRng = .Find(what:=txtToSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=.Cells(.Count))
    End With
    GetCellWithText = Not foundRng Is Nothing
End Function
```

and use it in your main code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRowsBetweenCellsWithSpecificTexts()
    Dim txt1Rng As Range, txt2Rng As Range

    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) ' reference currently active sheet column B range from row 1 down to last not empty one
        If Not GetCellWithText(.Cells, "Description", txt1Rng) Then Exit Sub ' if first text not found do nothing
        If Not GetCellWithText(.Cells, "Transportation", txt1Rng) Then Exit Sub ' if second text not found do nothing

        If txt2Rng.Row = txt1Rng.Row + 1 Then Exit Sub ' if found cells are adjacent then do nothing
    End With

    Range(txt1Rng.Offset(1), txt2Rng.Offset(-1)).Delete
End Sub
```

this code acts on the currently active sheet

if you need to run it on a specific sheet then just ad proper sheet specifications before Range calls (i.e. `Worksheets("MySheetName").Range(...)`)